# Creating semi-transparent, round cornered with border Window in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, user-interface

What would be the best approach for creating a Window that is semi-transparent, has round corners and an outline around its border and the arrow, but without the the title bar and buttons.

The window will pop up from the Menu Bar when a use clicks on the menu bar icon.

I'm looking to have an effect similar to the "Applications" and "Downloads" windows:

[image]

I guess I will need to do the drawing myself. But I'm wondering what's the best way to do this and whether there is anything already built into Cocoa that can minimize the effort? Or maybe a 3rd party project that has already done that (couldn't find anything exactly like that)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your window with

`- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(NSUInteger)windowStyle backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType defer:(BOOL)deferCreation`

with a style-mask of `NSBorderlessWindowMask` which will give an unadorned window. Its how the Dock does its mechanics too.

Note that you must init with this style , you can't change an already init'ed windows style.

Place a custom `NSView` via the `contentView` accessor with your desired background custom drawing at the top of the windows view stack.

You might need also to `setOpaque` to `NO`

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for has been done a lot. Too much really. 
The classes you want to look into are as follows.

NSStatusItem
This is something that appears in the status bar section of the menu bar to the right side.

NSMenu
If you want this from a menu in the application menus, you'll need to do some clever things with views in menus.

NSWindow
As the other poster notes a borderless window is one way to achieve this.

NSPopover
This is another way. Combined with the above, a fancy technique is to use a clear window called a cover window then, when clicking on the menu or status menu, invoke a popover from a point below that in the clear cover window.

That should be enough to get you started with what you should look into.

Beyond that, peruse the Mac App Store and also look at cocoacontrols.com and GitHub.